# When RequestQueue is used with the RequestFuture is blocking another requests in android while using VOLLEY

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using google's **VOLLEY** library.
I have a RequestQueue in which I am making the RequestFuture object requests and it is blocking another requests and due to that UI is blocked in android.
All this Requests are being made in a service. How can I make RequestFuture should not block the another requests.

Regards.